# events no longer function after jquery animate

Tags: jquery, click, hover, jquery-animate

So after I animate some imgs or divs with javascript they no longer have click or hover events available to them. (The imgs in question are the 4 big bubbles after they line up behind the "n")

I'm sure this is a common problem that I just cant find the answer to. Thanks in advance!

Live Code: http://jboullion.com/nebuloid/index.html

Here are 3 different variations on my html divs

```
<div >
  <a href="javascript:link()"> <img id="bubbleOne"  alt="Staff" src="images/smallbubble.png" /></a><br />
  </div>
  <div>
  <img id="bubbleTwo" onclick="link()" alt="Mission" src="images/smallbubble.png" /><br />
  </div>
  <div>
  <img id="bubbleThree" href="javascript:link()" alt="Games" src="images/smallbubble.png" /><br />
  </div>
```

**Here is my javascript**
-brief version

```
$("#bubbleOne").click(function(event)
  {
  fadeLogo()
    if (iOS == true) {
      window.scroll(0,350);
    }
    $("#copy").html("<span id='purp'>WE ARE NEBULOID</span> <br/><br/>We want to make great video games.<br/> We want to stretch the boundaries that define what video gaming looks and feels like.<br/> We are new developers cutting our teeth, and we have very grand and exciting projects coming soon.<br/> Our biggest upcoming project is a subtle, human, and epic science fiction adventure.");  
    $("#mission").css("color","#8470FF");
    colorHoldM = "#8470FF";
    colorHoldG = "white";
    colorHoldS = "white";
    colorHoldC = "white";
    $("#games").css("color","white");
    $("#staff").css("color","white");
    $("#contact").css("color","white");
  });

$("#bubbleOne").hover(function(){
  $("#bubbleOne").animate({
    width: "175px"}, 500 );
    });

    $("#bubbleOne").mouseout(function(){
  $("#bubbleOne").animate({
    width: "110px"}, 500 );
    });

    function fadeLogo()
    {
      //stuff
        $('#bubbleOne').delay(1000).animate({left: '+=120', top: '-=130' }, 1000);
        $('#bubbleTwo').delay(1000).animate({left: '-=50', top: '-=130' }, 1500);
        $('#bubbleThree').delay(1000).animate({left: '-=230', top: '-=165' }, 2000);
    //stuff
    }
```

Anyone know the answer?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by *the options break*?

Comment: sorry poor description. After imgs animate they no longer have click or hover events available to them

Comment: It looks like they do, to me, but then it's not really clear how that whole apparatus is meant to behave.  Can you provide steps to reproduce the problem?

Comment: after clicking on either one of the menu options at the top or on one of the 4 big bubbles the whole thing should animate so that the bubble float up next to the "N" after that they seem to lose their click and hover events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is that you are not hiding certain elements on your page via display:none but via opacity. So, these invisible elements are in front of your bubbles.

For example, if i find the element `$('#eb')` and set its display to none in firebug, i can now hover over the first 2 bubbles.

Also, you spelled the word 'Copyright' wrong :P maybe you should just replace it with `&copy;`

something like this should fix it:

```
var $shit = $('#eb,#u,#l,#oi,#d');
$shit.animate({opacity:0}, {duration: 1000, specialEasing:{duration: 1000, opacity:'easeInBounce'}, 'complete':function(){
   $shit.hide(); //function called when animation is complete. hide this shit
}});
```

You should also look into code reuse...

Comment: You rock. I didn't even think of that. I would hug you if I could.

Comment: For some reason I cannot get this animation complete function to trigger. Any ideas?

Comment: always read the docs first: http://api.jquery.com/animate/ - they indicate that you may need to put the compete function into the 2nd hash passed into the animate function. ill update my answer

Comment: I did try but was unable to understand what they were asking :( I really do appreciate your help though. I went through and condensed code and fixed the autocomplete